# Visual studio 2015 with update 3, source code ClearCase, running on Hyper-V, very slow

Tags: c++

I  have a problem with compilation time, on virtual machines running on Hyper-v, on windows server 2012 R2 STD. 
the virtual machine is installed with windows 10.
the source code is Clearcase.
compilation time on the virtual machine is very slow (6 hours). 
on physical PC (windows 10 and visual studio 2015 update 3) the compilation time is 2 hours.
what can be the problem?

Comment: Source code is located on the virtual drive?

Comment: What is the configuration of your VM? What is the RAM, virtual CPU core count, and how is storage configured? IO performance in virtual-machines tends to be considerably slower than a physical box, so maxing out RAM to avoid paging is essential - especially if you're doing desktop workloads in a VM - I recommend a minimum of 8GB RAM for the VM - so your host should have 16GB).